# Realm slow Insertion of data (primary key UUID().uuidString)

Tags: ios, swift, database, xcode, realm

I am using Realm database in one of my project. Everything was going fine until in one of the table I have to set a primary key as UUID().uuidString as suggested in realm documentation. The app has a sync mechanism where it gets data from server, parse JSON and inserts into Realm database.

In this table where primary key is set to UUID().uuidString, the data insertion becomes very slow as the data grows above 100k. At first I couldn't figure out what's wrong, is this the issue with my code or is this the problem with realm database. So, I created a new test project and discovered the strange behaviour of Realm when primary key is set to UUID().uuidString.

I performed 2 tests, firstly setting primary key as UUID().uuidString and secondly setting primary key as integer. The model, the code, number of data insertion (40k rows of data in each transaction) was same for both tests except difference in primary key value as mentioned. I found the result as below which was surprising.

**Realm Object**

```
class TestData: Object {

dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString // "For 1st test"
dynamic var id = 0 // "For 2nd test"
dynamic var graphNum = 0
dynamic var yAxis = 0
dynamic var xAxis = ""
dynamic var legend = ""
dynamic var year = ""

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}
```

}

**My Code**

```
        try! realm.write {
                for i in 0..<40000 { // 40000..<80000, 80000..<120000 ...... till 240000 for 2nd test
                    let data = TestData()
                    data.id = i //For 2nd test
                    data.legend = "02/01/17"
                    data.graphNum = 1346
                    data.xAxis = "Month"
                    data.yAxis = 9
                    data.year = "2017"
                    realm.add(data, update:true)
                }
        }
```

**Test 1: UUID().uuidString as primary key**

**Performed 6 transaction by a hitting a button.**

**Output**

Time taken to insert 40k rows of data per transaction.

1st hit -> 1.72675597667694 sec, total records in db -> 40k (fast insert)

2nd hit -> 1.76628297567368 sec, total records in db -> 80k (fast insert)

3rd hit -> 3.18893700838089 sec, total records in db -> 120k (getting slower)

4th hit -> 6.45702600479126 sec, total records in db -> 160k (getting slower)

5th hit -> 9.80401802062988 sec, total records in db -> 200k (getting slower)

6th hit -> 12.9913129806519 sec, total records in db -> 240k (getting more slower)

continue inserting the same number of data i.e 40k, the insertion time increases as data grows in table.

**Test 2: Int as a primary key**

**Performed same number of transaction**

**Output**

Time taken to insert 40k rows of data per transaction.

1st hit -> 2.36865001916885 sec, total records in db -> 40k (fast insert)

2nd hit -> 1.69827800989151 sec, total records in db -> 80k (fast insert)

3rd hit -> 1.62342000007629 sec, total records in db -> 120k (fast insert)

4th hit -> 1.70833700895309 sec, total records in db -> 160k (fast insert)

5th hit -> 1.6657919883728 sec, total records in db -> 200k (fast insert)

So, time taken to insert data was more or less same after I switched primary key from UUID.uuidString to other.

So, my question is, is this due to UUID.uuidString that my data insertion gets slow as data grows in table. Or, is there other way I can fix this issue even by setting primary key as UUID.uuidString.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: I'm not sure how Foundation's UUID is implemented, but could it possibly be the system entropy pool being drained (c.f. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30380/how-does-generating-random-numbers-remove-entropy-from-your-system)? What happens if you run the same experiment, but using a string-ified integer (e.g. "123") as your primary key?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Ok, yah I will try that using string as primary key and update the finding soon.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Actually, this was a long time ago and I have quite forgotten how I fixed it. But, I think I was performing write transaction in a loop which was causing this slowness.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed slow insertion issue by using this code.

```
func addAsBatch<T: Object>(_ data: [T]) {
    if !isRealmAccessible() { return }

    let realm = try! Realm()
    realm.refresh()

    realm.beginWrite()
    for object in data {
        realm.add(object)
    }
    try? realm.commitWrite()
}
```

Showing function use with your example -

```
let data = TestData()
data.id = i //For 2nd test
data.legend = "02/01/17"
data.graphNum = 1346
data.xAxis = "Month"
data.yAxis = 9
data.year = "2017"

addAsBatch(data)
```